# No visible @interface for 'WHMailActivity' declares the selector 'activityDidFinish:'

Tags: ios, objective-c

my error it No visible @interface for 'WHMailActivity' declares the selector 'activityDidFinish:'

I get a one night but I did not succeed. . . Why are so used elsewhere but I can not. . . 
Which I hope to help me. . .

Thanks in advance !

this it my .h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
#import "WHMailActivityItem.h"

@interface WHMailActivity : UIViewController

@end
```

and this it my .m

```
#import "WHMailActivity.h"

@interface WHMailActivity() <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong)WHMailActivityItem *activityItem;

@end


@implementation WHMailActivity

#pragma mark - UIActivity Overrides

- (NSString *)activityType {
    return NSStringFromClass([self class]);
}

- (NSString *)activityTitle {
    return NSLocalizedString(@"Mail", @"title for Mail activity item");
}

- (UIImage *)activityImage {
    return [UIImage imageNamed:@"mailActivity.png"];
}

- (BOOL)canPerformWithActivityItems:(NSArray *)activityItems {
    if (![MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
        return NO;
    }

    for (id item in activityItems) {
        if ([item isKindOfClass:[WHMailActivityItem class]]) {
            return YES;
        }
    }

    return NO;
}

- (void)prepareWithActivityItems:(NSArray *)activityItems {
    for (id item in activityItems) {
        if ([item isKindOfClass:[WHMailActivityItem class]]){
            self.activityItem = item;
        }
    }
}

- (UIViewController *)activityViewController {
    MFMailComposeViewController *composeController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

    if (self.activityItem.onMailActivitySelected) {
        self.activityItem.onMailActivitySelected(composeController);
    }

    composeController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
   return composeController;

        [self performSelector:@selector(mailComposeController)];
}

#pragma mark - MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error {
    [self activityDidFinish:result == MFMailComposeResultSent];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your .h file you have:

```
@interface WHMailActivity : UIViewController
```

but it should be:

```
@interface WHMailActivity : UIActivity
```

assuming the class is a custom `UIActivity`.